# Responding synchronously to a message, then updating that message asynchronously

Tags: google-hangouts

I don't see a way to get the message ID/name when responding synchronously in which case I can't update the message later. For instance, I'd like to respond immediately with "working on it...", then go off and do work, then update the message once the work is done.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I think you can do this with Google Chat now: https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/update

Comment: But I need to know the message id? How can I get it with synchronous response?